# Silverlight Save image to IsolatedStorage

Tags: c#, silverlight, image, isolatedstorage

Is the following the correct way to save an image to isolated storage?

```
    public void imageToStore(Image imageIn)
{
    IsolatedStorageFile iso = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication(); 
    IsolatedStorageFileStream s = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(imageIn.Name,    FileMode.Create, iso);

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(s))
            {
                writer.Write(imageIn);
            }           
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Thanks, Anthony: I completely missed the "Silverlight" part, the links below are for the System.Drawing classes. What you need is instead described in detail [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/kirillosenkov/archive/2009/10/12/saving-images-bmp-png-etc-in-wpf-silverlight.aspx) and can probably be adopted by you right away.

---

Original answer (just for reference, not applicable for your use case):

Look at the [Streamwriter Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.write.aspx) and tell me which method you'd expect to handle the Image you provide. You'll notice that there's no overload for this type, so - it falls back to the overload that takes an object. That doesn't know how to save an arbitrary object and just saves whatever .ToString() returns for this instance. From the link above:

> Writes the text representation of an
>   object to the text stream by calling
>   ToString on that object. (Inherited
>   from TextWriter.)

Fortunately the Image class has [a method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image_methods.aspx) that knows how to [save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.save.aspx) itself to a stream. Use that.